# problem with loading a url into safari

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I am using the below code to load a url into safari (iphone):

```
NSString *gotoURL = [self getPostID:indexPath.row];
//NSLog(gotoURL );
NSURL *url = [ [ NSURL alloc ] initWithString:gotoURL];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

the code works if I replace gotoURL with : @"http://www.example.com" but it wont if I replace it.

The gotoURL gets a url from getPostID (which also returns a NSString) and I did an nslog as you can see and the url format seems fine.

Any idea why its not working?

Comment: Is the `url` object non-`nil`?

Comment: its geting the value from gotoURL so its not nil ofcourse! (I hope that answered your questions)

Comment: Can you provide an a sample url being passed?

Comment: it looks like http://domain.tld/4Mi

Answer (score 3):

From what you've added, it is likely that you're missing the protocol in the url. The string passed must be `http://domain.tld/4Mi`.

Comment: thats the problem, its not @"", I am using function getPost to get the url from a webserver, so the result is passed through as you can see... thats exactly how the code is, all is missing is the function ... but its actually : 2011-05-23 02:31:16.990 ####-V2[8368:207] 
http://########.com/LLi   thats from the log

Comment: If this is the standard format, why can't you split the string using [`componentsSeparatedByString :`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByString:) to get an array whose 4th element is the url string that you need.

Comment: This should probably go into your parsing part though.

Comment: I am sorry but could you please add me on skype : ahoura.ghotbi  so I we can discuss this, thanks alot